# How to overcome array mutation in Js

Tags: javascript, mutation

Trying to overcome mutation of a list in a js function.
Ive been trying for hours using techniques such as `list.slice()` to make a duplicate of the array to be used. as well as other methods. I have boiled down my function to a more basic version shown here:

```
list = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

function listadjust(b) {
    for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        if (i == (b.length-1)) {
            b[i][1] = 1;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Its meant to take a multidimensional array input and change the second element of the last element. (The 6 in the variables `list` shown above. Any ways to overcome this would be great. Im not a programmer just need this for a really simple tool, and disappointed as to why it wont work. Thank you!

Comment: `.slice()` just creates a shallow copy of the array. You will have to call `.slice()` on each sub-array as well. You can also copy the whole array in one go using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(list));`.

Comment: You need to make a deep copy. A shallow copy only duplicates the top-level array, not the nested array.

Answer (score 0):

If your expectation is just to alter 2nd element of the last item like so:

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] -> [[1,2],[3,4],[5,1]]
[[4,3],[2,7],[8,4],[4,7]] -> [[4,3],[2,7],[8,4],[4,1]] 
[[1,2],[3,4]] -> [[1,2],[3,1]]
```

Then you can do this:

```js
function listadjust(b) {
    const newArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b))
    newArray[newArray.length - 1][1] = 1
    return newArray;
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, adjusted to not mutate :P.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work, the original list is still mutated

Answer (score 0):

Unlike your primitive types (ie. number or string), arrays are reference types. Which means when you assign an array to a variable, you're assigning a memory address and not the actual array itself, so all you need is to make a deep clone before made any modification on the array

```
list = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

const clone = (items) => items.map(item => Array.isArray(item) ? clone(item) : item);

function listadjust(b) {
    const arr = clone(b)
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i == (arr.length-1)) {
            arr[i][1] = 1;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A JS array is a reference, so the easiest way to create a copy that is NOT a reference is to turn it into a string, and then back into an array. Add this line of code as the first line in the function:

```
function listadjust(b) {
    b=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic solution.

```
let listOne = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
let listTwo = [[4,7],[4,1],[2,4],[8,4]];
let listThree = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[0,0,3,5],[2,5,7]];

function listAdjust(list, change = 1) {
    let newList = [...list];
    let last = newList[newList.length - 1];
    //Whatever we want to change it to
    last[1] = change;
    return newList;
}

console.log(listAdjust(listOne));
console.log(listAdjust(listTwo));
console.log(listAdjust(listThree));

// Which outputs to...
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 1 ] ]
[ [ 4, 7 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 8, 1 ] ]
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 0, 0, 3, 5 ], [ 2, 1, 7 ] ]
```

I changed added some examples to show that it works regardless of the length of the arrays. I also changed the function to accept an option second argument, of what you'd like to change it to. You can remove the 'change = 1' if you don't want it there, but if you do alter 'change' in the function to whatever you want to change it to. Of course you may want to replace the 1 in 'change = 1' which whatever you want the default to actually be.

Edit: I'm also not sure why people are coming up with strange convoluted ways of 'cloning' the array. You just need to use the ES6 method, which is to use the spread operator. See how I have 'let newList = [...list];' in the code? That basically creates a new array with the same values as the original array, but without simply changing the 'reference' to it.

Comment: The `let newList = [...list];` however will only shallow copy the array. The inner array elements are still mutated.